# Average of least number of vertices to delete to obtain a caterpillar tree

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $t=(V,E)$ be an $n$-vertex (free) tree ($n=|V|$); $V$ is the vertex set, $E$ is the edge set. There are many types of trees, among which we find *caterpillar* trees. As a friendly reminder, when the leaves of a caterpillar tree are removed you are left with a path graph. Here I'm referring to *unlabelled* trees only; there is only 1 tree of three vertices, 2 of four vertices, 3 of five vertices, ... These correspond to the sequence [A000055](https://oeis.org/A000055).

For any tree $t$, define the "*caterpillar distance* of $t$", denoted as $cat(t)$, as the minimum amount of vertices to be removed from $t$ to obtain a caterpillar tree. If $t$ is itself a caterpillar tree, then $cat(t)=0$.

I'm posting this question in the hope that it is interesting to the community, and because I don't have the training, or the knowledge, to explore this myself: what is the expected value of $cat(t)$ among all $n$-vertex trees?

I think I can put it a bit more formally. Let $C_n : \mathcal{T}_n \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ be a uniformly random variable on $\mathcal{T}_n$, the set of $n$-vertex free trees. For any $t\in\mathcal{T}_n$, define said variable as $C_n(t) = cat(t)$. What is the value of $\mathbb{E}[C_n]$? (where $\mathbb{E}[]$ is the expectation operator)

Let me add some values of this expected caterpillar distance for some values of $n$. The left column lists the expected values of the caterpillar distance, the average of the distance *over all trees*. The right column shows the expected values of the caterpillar distance conditioned to non-caterpillar trees, that is the average caterpillar distance *over non-caterpillar trees*.
[image]

I added the column to the right since I thought it makes more sense than having only the column to the left. I mean, we should expect $E[C_n]$ and $E[C_n\;|\;C]$ to converge to similar values as $n\rightarrow\infty$ since the amount of caterpillar trees is vanishingly small, and we can already see this at $n=22$.

I calculated these numbers using the [Linear Arrangement Library](https://github.com/LAL-project/linear-arrangement-library/) [for Python](https://github.com/LAL-project/python-interface):

```
import lal
for n in range(1,23):
    S = 0
    N = 0
    gen = lal.generate.all_ulab_free_trees(n)
    while not gen.end():
        t = gen.yield_tree()
        # if not t.is_of_tree_type(lal.graphs.tree_type.caterpillar):
        S += lal.properties.tree_caterpillar_distance(t)
        N += 1
    avg = lal.numeric.rational(S,N)
    print(n, avg, avg.to_double())
```

Comment: I don't know if this will turn out to affect the answer, but is $T_n$ the set of trees on $n$-labeled leaves, or the set of isomorphism classes of trees with $n$-leaves? (For example, when $n=4$, is the probability of a path equal to $12/16$, or $1/2$?)

Comment: Sorry, you're correct. I forgot to mention the labelling. I'll edit the post clarifying this, and I'll also post some probabilities. Regarding your question, for $n=4$, the probability of a path is $1/2$.

Comment: And yes, it does affect the answer if we change the set of trees. I thought it might be of some interest.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer, feel free to share your findings with us if you find any! :)